# Understanding the Uncertainty in momentum of wave function

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

For a wave function that is rectangular centered at origin and a finite value finite limits, why do I have to use the Fourier transform to find the uncertainty in momentum which turns out to be infinity instead of using the operator $\frac{h}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$ for finding $\Delta p$? If I do the same and find the square or the average, when I differentiate I get a zero! Am I missing something obvious? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uncertainty is defined as the Standard Deviation in Operators O

$\Delta O = <O^2> - <O>^2$

where $<>$ denotes taking the average with wave function $\psi$.

Now to your questions: If $O=p$, then Fourier transform makes it easier to calculate $<p^2>$ and $<p>$. The Expression

$\int_V d^3x \psi^* p \psi = -i \hbar\int_V d^3x \psi^* \frac{d}{dx} \psi = <p>$

turns to

$<p> = -i \hbar \int d^3k \phi^* k \phi$

if you use the Fourier-transformed wave function $\phi = \int_V d^3x \psi(x) e^{i kx}$.

Maybe you have computed the Differentiation of the rectangular wave function not properly. If the wave function has the value $A$ between $x = -b$ and $x = b$ and Zero otherwise, ist derivative is nonzero at $x = -b$ and $x = b$ due to the jump; you will have

$\frac{d \psi} {dx}= A \delta(x+b) - A \delta(x-b)$

with Dirac Delta Distribution $\delta$. After using this you would get the same result as that you have obtained by Fourier transform.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I did the exact mistake you pointed out, now I realize how important a dirac-delta function is !